# RuntimeException: Error in configuring object with null pointer exception while running my UDAF?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I've been trying to write a UDAF for calculating a weighted average. I wrote it in a way similar to the existing UDAF for calculating an average but it only seems to work on my local machine. I am not sure whats wrong....has someone come across a similar problem
the following is the error generated:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:270)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at                        org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:264)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:88)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
     at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:34)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:88)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecMapper.configure(ExecMapper.java:121)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.initializeOp(GroupByOperator.java:325)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeChildren(Operator.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.initializeOp(SelectOperator.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initializeChildren(Operator.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator.initializeOp(TableScanOperator.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.initializeOp(MapOperator.java:441)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.initialize(Operator.java:360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecMapper.configure(ExecMapper.java:98)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: I solved the problem..it seems that there was some jar file issue...whenever i exported some of the changes would work while some wouldn't so I guess the answer would be to terminate your hive session every time u plan to add a jar file! :/ strange but it worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem..it seems that there was some jar file issue...whenever i exported some of the changes would work while some wouldn't so I guess the answer would be to terminate your hive session every time u plan to add a jar file! :/ strange but it worked...

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was running Hive query (select statement from  a table which was created by using a serde jar), but when I was making the select query that jar was missing from the classpath. So I added jar into classpath in the hive shall by using the following command: -

add jar /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-contrib-0.7.0-cdh3u0.jar;

and then made the select query it resolved my issue.